# Merge two ArrayLists with no duplicate subclasses

Tags: java, arraylist

Given:

```
public abstract class Cars {}

...

public class Ford extends Cars {}

...

public class Dodge extends Cars {}

...

public class Volkswagen extends Cars {}

...
```

If I have two ArrayList objects:

```
List<Cars> dealer1 = new ArrayList<>;
List<Cars> dealer2 = new ArrayList<>;

dealer1.addAll(asList(new Ford("ford1"), new Dodge("dodge1")));
dealer2.addAll(asList(new Dodge("dodge2"), new Volkswagen("vw1")));
```

I then want to create a merged list from the two with only one instance of each subclass, such that:

```
dealerMerged = ["ford1", "dodge1", "vw1"]
```

OR

```
dealerMerged = ["ford1", "dodge2", "vw1"]
```

It doesn't matter which instance makes it into the merged list.

Is this possible? I had a search through and saw something about using Set but that seems to only ensure unique references, unless I've badly misunderstood something.

Comment: It's possible, but you'll never know till you try.

Comment: Set will identify duplicates and wont add elements if present, it uses **equals** and **hashCode** methods to identify duplicates. You have to override those methods in your sub classes and tell  on which attribute you have to identify duplicates, otherwise it will check duplicates based on address of the objects, like you said **unique references**

Comment: Imagine in real life I handed you two bags. In each bag was a random assortment of fruits and vegetables. I want you to give me one bag back that has one fruit and one vegetable in it. Don't care which they are. How would you do it? Think of the steps you'd take. Then translate those steps to code.

Comment: Here is a hint:

https://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator

Comment: not entirely related, but brands are not often modeled as subclasses, but rather as a property

Answer (score 2):

### Overriding equals() will work but DON'T

You can always make your collection distinctful converting it to a `Set` (as @Arun states in comment) or using `distinct` operation over the Stream of your collections. But remember those approaches use the `equal()` methods for that. So a quick thinking would be overriding `equals()` and return its `Class` type. But wait ! If you do so you will end up having all `Dodge` objects equals to each other despite they have different properties like name `dodge1`, `dodge2`. You may not only handle a single business in read world. `equal()` method has lots of other significances. So stay away of doing so.

### If you are thinking a Java 8 way, Stateful Filter is perfect

We have a choice to use the `filter` operation for our concatenated stream. `filter` operation works pretty straight forward. It takes a predicate and decide which element to take or ignore. This a commonly used function that you will find all over the blogs that solves this problem.

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctBy(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```

Here the `distinctBy` function returns a predicate (that will be used in `filter` operation). It maintains state about what it's seen previously and returns whether the given element was seen for the first time. (You can read further explanation about this [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java-8/java-stream-distinct-examples/))

You can use this *Stateful Filter* like

```
Stream.of(dealer1, dealer2)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .filter(distinctBy(Cars::getClass))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .forEach(cars -> System.out.println(cars));
```

### So What we actually did here ?

- We concatenated the 2 `ArrayList` with `flatmap` that will give us a single stream of the merged elements (If you are new to Stream API. See this [Stream Concatenation](https://www.techempower.com/blog/2016/10/19/efficient-multiple-stream-concatenation-in-java/) article
- We then exploits the `filter()` operation that is feed with the `distinctBy` method which return a predicate.
- And you see a `ConcurrentHashMap` is maintained to track which element satisfies the predicate or not by a boolean flag.
- And the predicate uses the `getClass()` method which returns the full class name, that distinguise the elements as subclasses
- We then can `collect` or iterate over the filtered list.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Map instead of List. You may please try following solution. This will let you put Car instances by their types. Thereby you will always have only one entry per class (this will be the latest entry in your map by the way).

```
public class CarsCollection {
    Map<Class<? extends Cars>, ? super Cars> coll = new HashMap<>();

    public <T extends Cars> void add(Class<T> cls, T obj) {
        coll.put(cls, obj);
    }
}

public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        CarsCollection nos1 = new CarsCollection();

        cars.add(Ford.class, new Ford("ford1"));
        cars.add(Dodge.class, new Dodge("dodge1"));

        cars.add(Dodge.class, new Dodge("dodge2"));
        cars.add(Volkswagen.class, new Volkswagen("vw1"));

        System.out.println(cars);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add all the element of the first list into the result list (assuming there is no duplicate in the first list) and then loop through the second list and add the elements to the resulting list only if there is no instance of the same class in the first list.

That could look something like this :

```
dealerMerged = dealer1;
boolean isAlreadyRepresented;
for (car2 : dealer2) {
    isAlreadyRepresented = false;
    for (car1 : dealer1) {
        if (car1.getClass().equals(car2.getClass())) {
            isAlreadyRepresented = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isAlreadyRepresented) {
        dealerMerged.add(car2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use class of the object as key in the map. This example with Java stream does exactly that:

```
List<Cars> merged = Stream.of(dealer1, dealer2)
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .collect( Collectors.toMap( Object::getClass, Function.identity(), (c1, c2) -> c1 ) )
                    .values()
                        .stream().collect( Collectors.toList() );
```